# Using arbitrary variables as namespaces for `exec`

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-code

With this test code using `exec` (using Python 3.4):

```
vals = {}
exec('def fun(): print("Hello from fun")', vals)
exec('def main(): fun()', vals)
vals['main']()
```

The output is:

> Hello from fun

But I did not expect this to work, since I assumed that `fun` and `main` where interpreted as separate code pieces without a common namespace to resolve the reference in `main` to `fun`.

So how can execution of `main` resolve the reference to `fun`?

---

Addition based understanding the issue.  With `print` of `id` for `vals` and `globals`, it becomes clear that the two functions sees the same globals:

```
vals = {}
print('id(vals):', id(vals))
exec('def fun(): print("fun id(globals()):", id(globals())); print("Hello from fun")', vals)
exec('def main(): print("main id(globals()):", id(globals())); fun()', vals)
vals['main']()
```

Which gives:

> id(vals): 32271016
>
> main id(globals()): 32271016
>
> fun id(globals()): 32271016
>
> Hello from fun

So the `vals` is used as globals for the code in `exec`, thus giving the connection, as @Dunes and other comments described.  Thanks.

Comment: Through `vals`, which you *explicitly provided*. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec

Comment: It might be helpful to add `print vals` after each `exec` line.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm guessing the OPs actually after https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#exec - where `exec` is a function and not a statement...

Comment: @JonClements ah, perhaps, but the same syntax works in both!

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's `True` :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By providing `vals` to both `exec` functions, you have provided the common namespace. The second argument to `exec` is a dictionary to use for global references in any code that is executed. When the first statement is executed it creates `fun` and stores it in the global namespace (`vals`). Thus, when when `main` tries to find `fun`, it finds that it is not a local variable and so tries to lookup `fun` in its globals (which is also `vals`). Since `fun` exists in `vals` the lookup works and the function retrieved and called. If gave each `exec` its own `dict` then this wouldn't work. If you don't provide `vals` then the current globals that `exec` is called in is used as the globals (so this would still work).